# Scrollviewer edge blur effect, opacitymask not working properly

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I want to create a custom scrollviewer control for a touch screen application without using scrollbars. To accomplish letting the users know that they can scroll the content, I am fading the bottom and top part of the scrollviewer with a linear gradient using an opacitymask. This all works fine, except for a problem with the opacitymask applying to the textblock in addition to the scrollviewer!

What I mean is, I would like the fading effect to apply to the top 1% and bottom 1% of the scrollviewer, and then the middle of the scrollviewer will be visible. The problem, however, is that this effect is also happening on the  control within the scrollviewer as well, even if i set OpacityMask="{x:Null}" on the textblock.

I have tried applying the opacitymask to the  outside of the scrollviewer as well but the same problem happens. Does the Opacitymask property apply to the children as well? Is there a better way to doing this fading effect?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="130">
    <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="2"
                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
        <ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.9" />
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,10" Style="{StaticResource textSmall}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I find it interesting that it appears to behave correctly in the designer view in Visual Studio.  If I add a large margin to the top of the text, it is not faded at all in the designer, but at runtime it is faded despite not being close to the top of the ScrollViewer control.  I wonder if this is a bug?

Comment: Edit:  It appears correctly in the designer when I have a StackPanel that contains the TextBlock.  If I have the TextBlock alone, it is faded on top and bottom in the designer, so disregard that comment.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older question, but I came across this question because I was trying to do something similar; so I figured I'd post my solution for the next person.  Any feedback on my solution is appreciated.

In our application, most of our ScrollViewer controls sit on top of non-scrolling textures, so we wanted the scrollable content to fade into that background at the edges of the ScrollViewer, but only when there was more content in that direction.  In addition, we have at least one 2-axis scrollable area where the user can pan around in every direction.  It had to work in that scenario as well.  Our application also doesn't really have scrollbars, but I've left that out of the solution I present here (it doesn't impact the solution).

Features of this solution:

1. Fades the edges of the content within the ScrollViewer if there is content along that side of the ScrollViewer that is not currently visible.
2. Decreases the intensity of the fade effect as you scroll closer to the edge of the content.
3. Gives some control over how the faded edges look.  Specifically, you can control:

   1. Thickness of the faded edge
   2. How opaque the content is at the outermost edge (or how "intense" the fade is)
   3. How fast the fade effect disappears as you scroll near the edge

The basic idea is to control an opacity mask over the scrollable content in the ScrollViewer's template.  The opacity mask contains a transparent outer border, and an inner opaque border with the BlurEffect applied to it to get the gradient effect at the edges.  Then, the margin of the inner border is manipulated as you scroll around to control how "deep" the fade appears along a particular edge.

This solution subclasses the ScrollViewer, and requires you to specify a change to the ScrollViewer's template.  The ScrollContentPresenter needs to be wrapped inside a Border named "PART_ScrollContentPresenterContainer".

The FadingScrollViewer class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

namespace ScrollViewerTest
{
  public class FadingScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
  {
    private const string PART_SCROLL_PRESENTER_CONTAINER_NAME = "PART_ScrollContentPresenterContainer";

    public double FadedEdgeThickness { get; set; }
    public double FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed { get; set; }
    public double FadedEdgeOpacity { get; set; }

    private BlurEffect InnerFadedBorderEffect { get; set; }
    private Border InnerFadedBorder { get; set; }
    private Border OuterFadedBorder { get; set; }



    public FadingScrollViewer()
    {
      this.FadedEdgeThickness = 20;
      this.FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed = 4.0;
      this.FadedEdgeOpacity = 0.0;

      this.ScrollChanged += FadingScrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
      this.SizeChanged += FadingScrollViewer_SizeChanged;
    }



    private void FadingScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.InnerFadedBorder == null)
        return;

      var topOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(this.VerticalOffset); ;
      var bottomOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(this.ScrollableHeight - this.VerticalOffset);
      var leftOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(this.HorizontalOffset);
      var rightOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(this.ScrollableWidth - this.HorizontalOffset);

      this.InnerFadedBorder.Margin = new Thickness(leftOffset, topOffset, rightOffset, bottomOffset);
    }



    private double CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(double edgeOffset)
    {
      var innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness = this.FadedEdgeThickness / 2.0;
      var calculatedOffset = (innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness) - (1.5 * (this.FadedEdgeThickness - (edgeOffset / this.FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed)));

      return Math.Min(innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness, calculatedOffset);
    }



    private void FadingScrollViewer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.OuterFadedBorder == null || this.InnerFadedBorder == null || this.InnerFadedBorderEffect == null)
        return;

      this.OuterFadedBorder.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
      this.OuterFadedBorder.Height = e.NewSize.Height;

      double innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness = this.FadedEdgeThickness / 2.0;
      this.InnerFadedBorder.Margin = new Thickness(innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness);
      this.InnerFadedBorderEffect.Radius = this.FadedEdgeThickness;
    }



    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();

      BuildInnerFadedBorderEffectForOpacityMask();
      BuildInnerFadedBorderForOpacityMask();
      BuildOuterFadedBorderForOpacityMask();
      SetOpacityMaskOfScrollContainer();
    }



    private void BuildInnerFadedBorderEffectForOpacityMask()
    {
      this.InnerFadedBorderEffect = new BlurEffect()
        {
          RenderingBias = RenderingBias.Performance,
        };
    }



    private void BuildInnerFadedBorderForOpacityMask()
    {
      this.InnerFadedBorder = new Border()
        {
          Background = Brushes.Black,
          HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
          VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
          Effect = this.InnerFadedBorderEffect,
        };
    }



    private void BuildOuterFadedBorderForOpacityMask()
    {
      byte fadedEdgeByteOpacity = (byte)(this.FadedEdgeOpacity * 255);

      this.OuterFadedBorder = new Border()
        {
          Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(fadedEdgeByteOpacity, 0, 0, 0)),
          ClipToBounds = true,
          Child = this.InnerFadedBorder,
        };
    }



    private void SetOpacityMaskOfScrollContainer()
    {
      var opacityMaskBrush = new VisualBrush()
        {
          Visual = this.OuterFadedBorder
        };

      var scrollContentPresentationContainer = this.Template.FindName(PART_SCROLL_PRESENTER_CONTAINER_NAME, this) as UIElement;

      if (scrollContentPresentationContainer == null)
        return;

      scrollContentPresentationContainer.OpacityMask = opacityMaskBrush;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the XAML to use the control, with the most minimal changes to the default ScrollViewer template required (it's the Border around the ScrollContentPresenter).

```
<local:FadingScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10" FadedEdgeThickness="20" FadedEdgeOpacity="0" FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed="4">
  <local:FadingScrollViewer.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
      <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenterContainer">
          <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        </Border>

        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </local:FadingScrollViewer.Template>


  <!-- Your content here -->

</local:FadingScrollViewer>
```

Note these additional properties on the FadedScrollViewer: FadedEdgeThickness, FadedEdgeOpacity, and FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed

- FadedEdgeThickness: How thick do you want the fade to be (in pixels)
- FadedEdgeOpacity: How opaque do you want the outer-most edge of the fade to be.  0 = completely transparent at the edge, 1 = do not fade at all at the edge
- FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed: Controls how fast the faded edge appears to disappear as you get close to it.  The higher the value, the slower the fade out.

Comment: This is good. There aren't many solutions to this out there and fewer that are good. This is such an easy task with CSS, it is almost embarrassing how difficult this is in WPF but thanks for taking the time to come up with a decent solution.

Comment: Nice solution. As for feedback that you requested, I found it useful to make your FadedEdgeThickness, FadedEdgeOpacity, and FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed Dependency Properties so that I can parameterize instances of the FadingScrollViewer in Xaml.  Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 4):

I changed Grandpappy's code to work without using a custom control.
Like this you can "upgrade" all your ScrollViewers to fading scrollviewers just by adding an attached Property to them.
You also need to specify a style for the scrollviewer, which i did anyway. It has to define the name PART_ScrollContentPresenterContainer. You can use Grandpappys Style without modifications.

The Code for the class (called it ScrollViewerExtensions) is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Attached property that makes the scrollbar fade on it's edges
/// 
/// derived class at from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901709/scrollviewer-edge-blur-effect-opacitymask-not-working-properly
/// </summary>
public class ScrollViewerExtensions : DependencyObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MAIN property: this activates the whole fading effect
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FadedEdgeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FadedEdgeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(20.0d, OnFadedEdgeThicknessChanged));

    public static void SetFadedEdgeThickness(ScrollViewer s, double value)
    {
        s.SetValue(FadedEdgeThicknessProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetFadedEdgeThickness(ScrollViewer s, double value)
    {
        return (double)s.GetValue(FadedEdgeThicknessProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// optional property. changes how fast the fade appears/diappears when scrolling near an edge
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FadedEdgeFalloffSpeedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(4.0d, OnFadedEdgeFalloffSpeedChanged));

    public static void SetFadedEdgeFalloffSpeed(ScrollViewer s, double value)
    {
        s.SetValue(FadedEdgeFalloffSpeedProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetFadedEdgeFalloffSpeed(ScrollViewer s, double value)
    {
        return (double)s.GetValue(FadedEdgeFalloffSpeedProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// optional property. changes how opaque the outermost edge should be
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FadedEdgeOpacityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FadedEdgeOpacity", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(0.0d, OnFadedEdgeOpacityChanged));

    public static void SetFadedEdgeOpacity(ScrollViewer s, double value)
    {
        s.SetValue(FadedEdgeOpacityProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetFadedEdgeOpacity(ScrollViewer s, double value)
    {
        return (double)s.GetValue(FadedEdgeOpacityProperty);
    }




    private const string PART_SCROLL_PRESENTER_CONTAINER_NAME = "PART_ScrollContentPresenterContainer";

    private static Dictionary<ScrollViewer, FadeSettings> Settings = new Dictionary<ScrollViewer, FadeSettings>();



    /// <summary>
    /// this is kindof the constructor for the properties. If you don't specify this, nothing will fade!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public static void OnFadedEdgeThicknessChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = d as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer == null)
            return;

        double edgeThickness = (double)e.NewValue;

        scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += FadingScrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
        scrollViewer.SizeChanged += FadingScrollViewer_SizeChanged;

        if (!Settings.ContainsKey(scrollViewer))
            Settings.Add(scrollViewer, new FadeSettings());

        Settings[scrollViewer].FadedEdgeThickness = edgeThickness;
    }


    public static void OnFadedEdgeFalloffSpeedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = d as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer == null)
            return;

        double edgeFalloffSpeed = (double)e.NewValue;

        if (!Settings.ContainsKey(scrollViewer))
            Settings.Add(scrollViewer, new FadeSettings());

        Settings[scrollViewer].FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed = edgeFalloffSpeed;
    }


    public static void OnFadedEdgeOpacityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = d as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer == null)
            return;

        double edgeOpacity = (double)e.NewValue;

        if (!Settings.ContainsKey(scrollViewer))
            Settings.Add(scrollViewer, new FadeSettings());

        Settings[scrollViewer].FadedEdgeOpacity = edgeOpacity;
    }


    private static void FadingScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        FadeSettings settings = Settings[scrollViewer];

        if (settings.InnerFadedBorder == null)
            return;

        var topOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(scrollViewer, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset); ;
        var bottomOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(scrollViewer, scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight - scrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
        var leftOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(scrollViewer, scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset);
        var rightOffset = CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(scrollViewer, scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth - scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset);

        settings.InnerFadedBorder.Margin = new Thickness(leftOffset, topOffset, rightOffset, bottomOffset);
    }

    private static void FadingScrollViewer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        FadeSettings settings = Settings[scrollViewer];

        if (!settings.Initialized) // abuse the SizeChanged event to call the OnApplyTemplate method. We can't override it, so we need something, that fires after it would normally be called. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351483%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
        {
            OnApplyTemplate(scrollViewer);
            settings.Initialized = true;
        }

        if (settings.OuterFadedBorder == null || settings.InnerFadedBorder == null || settings.InnerFadedBorderEffect == null)
            return;

        settings.OuterFadedBorder.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        settings.OuterFadedBorder.Height = e.NewSize.Height;

        double innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness = settings.FadedEdgeThickness / 2.0;
        settings.InnerFadedBorder.Margin = new Thickness(innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness);
        settings.InnerFadedBorderEffect.Radius = settings.FadedEdgeThickness;
    }

    private static double CalculateNewMarginBasedOnOffsetFromEdge(ScrollViewer scrollViewer, double edgeOffset)
    {
        FadeSettings settings = Settings[scrollViewer];

        var innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness = settings.FadedEdgeThickness / 2.0;
        //var calculatedOffset = (innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness) - (1.0 * (this.FadedEdgeThickness - (edgeOffset / this.FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed)));

        double calculatedOffset;
        if (edgeOffset == 0)
            calculatedOffset = -innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness;
        else
            calculatedOffset = (edgeOffset * settings.FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed) - innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness;

        return Math.Min(innerFadedBorderBaseMarginThickness, calculatedOffset);
    }

    public static void OnApplyTemplate(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        BuildInnerFadedBorderEffectForOpacityMask(scrollViewer);
        BuildInnerFadedBorderForOpacityMask(scrollViewer);
        BuildOuterFadedBorderForOpacityMask(scrollViewer);
        SetOpacityMaskOfScrollContainer(scrollViewer);
    }

    private static void BuildInnerFadedBorderEffectForOpacityMask(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        FadeSettings settings = Settings[scrollViewer];

        settings.InnerFadedBorderEffect = new BlurEffect()
        {
            RenderingBias = RenderingBias.Performance,
        };
    }

    private static void BuildInnerFadedBorderForOpacityMask(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        FadeSettings settings = Settings[scrollViewer];

        settings.InnerFadedBorder = new Border()
        {
            Background = Brushes.Black,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            Effect = settings.InnerFadedBorderEffect,
        };
    }

    private static void BuildOuterFadedBorderForOpacityMask(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        FadeSettings settings = Settings[scrollViewer];

        byte fadedEdgeByteOpacity = (byte)(settings.FadedEdgeOpacity * 255);

        settings.OuterFadedBorder = new Border()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(fadedEdgeByteOpacity, 0, 0, 0)),
            ClipToBounds = true,
            Child = settings.InnerFadedBorder,
        };
    }

    private static void SetOpacityMaskOfScrollContainer(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        FadeSettings settings = Settings[scrollViewer];

        var opacityMaskBrush = new VisualBrush()
        {
            Visual = settings.OuterFadedBorder
        };

        var scrollContentPresentationContainer = scrollViewer.Template.FindName(PART_SCROLL_PRESENTER_CONTAINER_NAME, scrollViewer) as UIElement;

        if (scrollContentPresentationContainer == null)
            return;

        scrollContentPresentationContainer.OpacityMask = opacityMaskBrush;

        // test
        /*var container = scrollContentPresentationContainer as Border;
        var scroller = container.Child as UIElement;
        container.Child = null;

        Grid g = new Grid();
        container.Child = g;

        g.Children.Add(scroller);
        this.OuterFadedBorder.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        g.Children.Add(this.OuterFadedBorder);*/
    }


    protected class FadeSettings
    {
        public BlurEffect InnerFadedBorderEffect { get; set; }
        public Border InnerFadedBorder { get; set; }
        public Border OuterFadedBorder { get; set; }

        public double FadedEdgeThickness { get; set; }
        public double FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed { get; set; }
        public double FadedEdgeOpacity { get; set; }

        public bool Initialized { get; set; }

        public FadeSettings()
        {
            FadedEdgeThickness = 20.0d;
            FadedEdgeFalloffSpeed = 4.0d;
            FadedEdgeOpacity = 0.0d;
        }
    }
}
```

You can either set the attached property in code:

```
scroller.SetValue(ScrollViewerExtensions.FadedEdgeThicknessProperty, 70.0d);
```

or you define it directly in XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" controls:ScrollViewerExtensions.FadedEdgeThickness="40">
    some content
</ScrollViewer>
```

Hope you guys can do something with it!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a control with a transparent gradient on top of the ScrollViewer within the same Grid and set its 'IsHitTestVisible' to false to achieve this effect.  Here is a modified version of your example using a Canvas control on top of the ScrollViewer:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="130">
            <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="2"
                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,30,10,30" TextWrapping="Wrap" OpacityMask="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                </TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Canvas Width="200" Height="130" Focusable="False" IsEnabled="False" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.9" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
```

I added a background color to the ScrollViewer and a large top margin to the TextBlock so that it would be easy to confirm the desired effect.  Here is what the output looked like:
[image]

Comment: This is what I had before I started using OpacityMask. The reason I switched over to OpacityMask was because of a background image on the grid that would get the white box on top of it, which I don't want. I want it to be transparent instead, which OpacityMask achieves.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand.  The gradient I am drawing is mostly transparent, just like the OpacityMask.  Rather than go from white to black to white in the gradient, I go from white to transparent to white.  It shouldn't cover the background image except with the faded white at the top and the bottom.  If this is what you were trying to avoid, then I am once again stumped. :)

Comment: Yeah, the faded white part is what is overlapping the image, which isn't what I want it to do. I really have no idea what I can do to get rid of that opacitymask on the textblock :(

Answer (score 2):

Antoine is right except he has it backward. You need to set the background color on the textblock to white or transparent or whatever you are wanting.

```
 <Grid Background="LightGray">
    <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="2"
                       HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
        <ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.9" />
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,10"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200" Background="White">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If you remove the TextBlock background you will notice the text in the textblock will fade out but with the background defined it is only applying it to the scrollviewer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  This is definitely the simplest, most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today, and the solution is actually very simple: set the ScrollViewer.Background property to anything but null (in your case you'd want Transparent), and it works.

I'm posting the answer here as it's the only question I found regarding this problem.